# How to get distinct count for last x weeks data but group by week in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a below query which I run gives me the single count for `month` as current month and `dates_for_week` has list of all the dates for last week from Sunday to Saturday.

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
AND year = '2020'
-- this is for month october but week 43
and (month = '10' and dates_for_week IN  ('18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'))
```

As of now the output I see is this -

```
Count
-----
982
```

Now I am trying to make this query dynamic such that it can give me count for past 6 weeks something like below as an output:

```
Count   Week
------------
982     W43
123     W42
126     W41
127     W40
128     W39
129     W38
```

I am able to convert above query in a dynamic way which gives me the count for current month october and previous week which is 43 and it works fine as shown below but I am not sure how can I change it so that it can give me data for all past 6 weeks in the above output format. It looks like I need to change the month also dynamically for some week to get output for past 6 weeks.

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
AND year = '2020'
-- this is for month october but week 43
and (
    month = extract(month from current_date)
    and dates_for_week IN (
            select
                date_part('d',((DATE_TRUNC('week', CURRENT_DATE) - 9) + row_number() over (order by true))::date)
            from process.data
            limit 7
  )
)
```

So what I need is this for last 6 week and group by week to give me the count as shown above. Is this possible to do by any chance?

```
and (month = '10' and dates_for_week IN  ('18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'))
and (month = '10' and dates_for_week IN  ('11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17'))
and (month = '10' and dates_for_week IN  ('4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'))
and (month IN ('9', '10') and dates_for_week IN  ('27', '28', '29', '30', '1', '2', '3'))
and (month = '9' and dates_for_week IN  ('20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26'))
and (month = '9' and dates_for_week IN  ('13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19'))
```

Comment: I had to read Philipp Johannis' answer to finally understand that `dates_for_week` is just the number of the day in the date, e.g. 29 for 2020-10-29. The name confused me. Is there a reason why you store year, month, and day separately? Why don't you just store dates as dates? That would make it much easier to query the data and would also prevent the database from storing invalid dates (such as 2020-02-30 or 2020-29-10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have years, months and days in seperate columns if I understand it correctly. I think the easiest way is to "build" a proper date column and then working with this column.

The following query should give you the last 6 weeks including the current week.

```
select 
EXTRACT(week from TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD')) week_num
,COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
and TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= DATEADD(day,-42,DATE_TRUNC('week', sysdate)) 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

However, there might be a challenge as weeks start on a Monday in redshift, so might need to do a slight manipulation (adding one day):

```
select 
EXTRACT(week from DATEADD(day,1,TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD'))) week_num
,COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
and DATEADD(day,1,TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD')) BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-42,DATE_TRUNC('week', sysdate)) AND DATEADD(day,-1,DATE_TRUNC('week', sysdate)) 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

### Debugging:

I would start running this query first, to check if the date is calculated properly

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
AND year = '2020'
-- this is for month october but week 43
and TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD') between '2020-10-18' and '2020-10-24'
```

Afterwards I would see if the week is calculated correctly:

```
select 
EXTRACT(week from DATEADD(day,1,TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD'))) week_num
,COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
AND year = '2020'
-- this is for month october but week 43
and TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD') between '2020-10-18' and '2020-10-24'
group by 1
order by 1
```

And last but not least I would extend the timeframe and make it dynamic:

```
select 
EXTRACT(week from DATEADD(day,1,TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD'))) week_num
,COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
AND year = '2020'
-- this is for month october but week 43
and DATEADD(day,1,TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD')) Between DATEADD(day,-42,DATE_TRUNC('week', sysdate)) and DATEADD(day,-1,DATE_TRUNC('week', sysdate)) 
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: This is awesome. I learned a lot. I didn't know we can write query like this. Looks like I made it complicated on my own. Thank you for your help! Let me try this and understand as well.

Comment: I tried this query but somehow results are not matching if I compare this dynamic query output with manual query for each week. Also in my case I don't need it for current week, I need it for trailing six weeks meaning last week and then last 5 more weeks. Any idea why results are not matching? Is there any way to split this query so that I can debug it out and see what dates it is using for each week as I need Sunday to Saturday for each week.

Comment: Added some debugging and spotted a small mistake. I was substracting one day to get sunday to saturday - but I should have added one day. Could you retry?

Comment: I ran your all 3 query in debugging section - Data matches exactly if I use your first and second debugging query individually with my original manual query but I noticed few things if I run third debugging query. First thing I noticed from third query is, it gives data for week `37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43` but I just need last 6 weeks so I don't need week `37`. Second thing is for week `38, 39, 40, 41, 42` data matches exactly from third query with your first debugging query but week 43 data doesn't matches from third query with your first and second query. Any thoughts?

Comment: So the issue is with the calculated date range then I guess. Just double checked it, I think this should be really the correct where condition:
`and DATEADD(day,1,TO_DATE(year||'-'||month||'-'|| dates_for_week,'YYYY-MM-DD')) Between DATEADD(day,-42,DATE_TRUNC('week', sysdate)) and DATEADD(day,-1,DATE_TRUNC('week', sysdate)) 
` - You may need to play with the `-42` - this means you are going back 42 days, from the latest start of the week, which should be 6 weeks because 6*7 = 42.

Comment: yeah that did the trick. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help! I also have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602452/how-to-group-x-weeks-worth-of-data-in-redshift). I came up with the dynamic query but it doesn't give me any output back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have some kind of date column, you can simply use something like this

```
select date_part(w, {your_date_column) as week_number,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CLIENTID))
FROM process.data
where type = 'pots'
and stype= 'kites'
and tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
and comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
AND year = '2020'
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select year, week, COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENTID)
from process.data
where type = 'pots' and
      stype= 'kites' and
      tires IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl') and
      comp IN ('data', 'hello', 'world')
group by year, dates_for_week
order by year desc, week desc
limit 6;
```

This is assuming that you have a week column, which seems like a reasonable assumption.

This is a *simple* way to accomplish what you want to do.  I am guessing that on Redshift it should have decent performance.